# How to use a JNI native library from Grails application

Tags: java, tomcat, grails, java-native-interface, swig

I'm developing a Grails web application and I need to use a JNI native library to access some specific hardware. For a simple Java application (see below) it works fine. To do this I just have to add the JAR to the Java build path and specify the "Native library location" (I use SpringSource Tool Suite on Windows7).

Working example:

```
import conceptacid.nativedriver.Driver;
public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("starting...");
        System.loadLibrary("AudioCardDriver");
        Driver driver = Driver.instance();
        String driverDescription = driver.getDriverDescription();
        System.out.println( "Native application driver: " + driverDescription);
    }
}
```

However, when I try to add it into my Grails application it fails:
Bootstrap.groovy:

```
import conceptacid.nativedriver.Driver;

class BootStrap {

    def init = { servletContext ->
    System.loadLibrary("AudioCardDriver");
    Driver driver = Driver.instance();
    String driverDescription = driver.getDriverDescription();
    System.out.println( "Native application driver: " + driverDescription);
    }
    def destroy = {
    }
}
```

the first line `System.loadLibrary("AudioCardDriver");` is executed silently without any exception but the next line where I try to use my native code `Driver driver = Driver.instance();` fails:

```
Running script C:\grails\scripts\RunApp.groovy
Environment set to development
  [groovyc] Compiling 1 source file to D:\Projects3\mbr\target\classes
   [delete] Deleting directory C:\Users\VShmyrev\.grails\1.3.7\projects\mbr\tomcat
Running Grails application..
2012-02-24 15:19:49,690 [main] ERROR context.GrailsContextLoader  - Error executing  bootstraps: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: conceptacid.nativedriver.AudioCardDriverJNI.swig_module_init()V
org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerInvocationException:   java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError:   conceptacid.nativedriver.AudioCardDriverJNI.swig_module_init()V
at grails.util.Environment.evaluateEnvironmentSpecificBlock(Environment.java:251)

...

Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: conceptacid.nativedriver.AudioCardDriverJNI.swig_module_init()V
at conceptacid.nativedriver.AudioCardDriverJNI.swig_module_init(Native Method)
at conceptacid.nativedriver.AudioCardDriverJNI.<clinit>(AudioCardDriverJNI.java:70)
at conceptacid.nativedriver.Driver.instance(Driver.java:35)
at conceptacid.nativedriver.Driver$instance.call(Unknown Source)
at BootStrap$_closure1.doCall(BootStrap.groovy:7)
... 26 more
Application context shutting down...
```

I'm sure I put the DLL into a directory which is in my system PATH but it doesn't help.

What is the right way to use a native library in Grails application both in a development environment and in production?

Comment: Does the native DLL depend on other DLLs (excluding system DLLs)?

Comment: can you show a screenshot of your project tree?

Comment: whats swig_module_init()

Comment: @hmjd No, the DLL I'm trying to use doesn't depend on other DLLs

Comment: @L7ColWinters I use SWIG to generate Java proxies from my C++ classes. swig_module_init is generated and statically linked to the DLL. It seems that swig_module_init is the first native function called by Java code. See the tree attached.

Answer (score 2):

Your DLL needs to be on a path specified in the Java system property `java.library.path`.  On Windows the `PATH` environment variable and Linux the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable are added to this system property.  You can try logging the `java.library.path` system property to see if Java is looking in the right place for your DLL.

Comment: The 'java.library.path' property **DOES** contain the path to the folder where the DLL is.

Comment: Actually if the `java.library.path` is wrong then the exception is fired earlier: during the `System.LoadLibrary()` call and the exception is different. It is: ` Error executing bootstraps: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no AudioCardDriver in java.library.path`. So the problem is different: the DLL is loaded although the classes couldn't be found.

Comment: How to add anew path to java.library.path?

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that the native library is being loaded multiple times in different classloaders, so forking a new JVM when running the app might help.

Comment: I came to the same conclusion: it looks like Groovy runs in a different environment.

Comment: Look here for a possuible workaround:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16695000/unsatisfiedlinkerror-when-using-a-jni-native-library-from-grails-application