# Grails Logging not working in Forked Mode

Tags: grails, logging, log4j, fork

I'm having a problem where logging works correctly when I run tomcat in non-forked mode from grails, but does not work correctly in forked mode.

Here is my Log4j configuration:

**Config.groovy**:

```
// log4j configuration
log4j = {

appenders {
    file name:"fileLogger", file: "c:/logs/app-log.log", threshold: Level.DEBUG
}

debug fileLogger: ['com.foo', 'BootStrap']

info  fileLogger: ['org.springframework']

error fileLogger: [
        'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet',        // controllers
        'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.pages',          // GSP
        'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.sitemesh',       // layouts
        'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.mapping.filter', // URL mapping
        'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.mapping',        // URL mapping
        'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons',            // core / classloading
        'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins',            // plugins
        'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate',      // hibernate integration
        'org.hibernate',
        'net.sf.ehcache.hibernate']
}
```

When I run `grails run-app`, the log file is correcly populated.

However, when I change my `BuildConfig.groovy` file to run tomcat in forked mode:

***BuildConfig.groovy:***

```
grails.project.fork = [
    run: [maxMemory:1024, minMemory:64, debug:false, maxPerm:256]
]
```

The log file does not get populated.

Is there something wrong with my configuration?  Why would it work in one mode, but not the other?

Answer (score 0):

You have the threshold for the appender set to `DEBUG` level. I think in the forked tomcat mode the default level is set to `INFO`. In order to make it work for the forked mode you might need to increase the logging level to `INFO` and change DEBUGs to INFOs.

`info  fileLogger: ['org.springframework', 'com.foo', 'BootStrap']`

Comment: Although I disagree with the approach, I tried it anyway.  It didn't work.